# Object creation not responding

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a new object here.
Here is my code

```
function createAnObject(name, address) {
            var newObj = new Object();
            newObj.name = name;
            newObj.address = address;
            newObj.saySomething = function () {
                console.log("the name is" + this.name + " the addess is" + this.address)
            }
        }


        var ballack = createAnObject('ballack', 'Ndri');
        console.log(ballack.name);
```

but in console the error is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

I am confused here. Could  someone tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: first: you don't return the object. second: use the Object-literal, and don't add every property individually to the object. in ES6 this could be as short as `function createAnObject(name, address) {
  return { 
    name,
    address,
    saySomething(){ 
      console.log("the name is " + this.name + " the addess is " + this.address); 
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to return your `newObj` in your `createAnObject` function:

```
function createAnObject(name, address) {
  var newObj = new Object();
  newObj.name = name;
  newObj.address = address;
  newObj.saySomething = function () {
    console.log("the name is" + this.name + " the addess is" + this.address)
  }

  return newObj;
};

var ballack = createAnObject('ballack', 'Ndri');
console.log(ballack.name);  // Now outputs 'ballack'
```

Comment: thanks.. well i was reading Microsoft 70-480 book and they didn't mention that.. huh !

Comment: I don't know that book, but you mean, they didn't mention that if you want to return something from a function, then you have to, uhhh, return something from the function?

Answer (score 0):

In modern JS:

```
function createAnObject(name, address) {
  return {
    name, 
    address,
    saySomething() { 
      console.log("the name is", this.name, "the address is", this.address);
    }
  };
}

var ballack = createAnObject('ballack', 'Ndri');
console.log(ballack.name);
```

Answer (score -1):

You not returning the created object.

```
function createAnObject(name, address) {
            var newObj = new Object();
            newObj.name = name;
            newObj.address = address;
            newObj.saySomething = function () {
                console.log("the name is" + this.name + " the addess is" + this.address)
            }
```

return newObj;
            };

```
        var ballack = createAnObject('ballack', 'Ndri');
        console.log(ballack.name);
```

Working method above and here is a jsbin of it working: http://jsbin.com/xagisanema/edit?html,js,console

Comment: Thanks. Missed that. Fixed.

Answer (score -1):

You have to return the `newObj` inside the `createAnObject` method.

Just add the return at the end of the method,

```
return newObj;
```